# What phrases use the word "en" like in the sentence, "Pienso en ti mucho."

Tags: gramática, modismos

I was corrected by a friend when I told her that I think about her a lot.

She said:

> No, no. Diga `Pienso EN ti`, no `DE` ti.

How many other phrases make use of the word `"en"` like this?

Answer (score 1):

En particular, la cuestión no es con `"en"` sino con el verbo que le precede, en este caso `"pienso"` pero podría ser `"creo", "confío", "encuentro"`, entre otros. Digo esto porque cuando estos verbos se usan para referirse a una persona van acompañados de "en" mientras que cuando se usan para referirse a una idea (o en una construcción más compleja) se utiliza "que", "de" o alguna otra palabra. Algunos ejemplos son:

> ¿Qué piensas **acerca de** mi trabajo?

O simplemente

> ¿Qué piensas **de** mi trabajo?

O también

> ¿Qué piensas **sobre** mi trabajo?

A su vez, la palabra `"en"` puede usarse para significar `"adentro"` como en

> Cayó **en** la piscina.

Pero hay cosas a las que no les cabe este uso como

> Creo **en** la ciencia pero no ciegamente como otros creen **en** la religión.

La respuesta de por qué es así (o en cuántos casos ocurre) no la tengo pero ocurre en todos los idiomas que ciertos verbos requieren que se use alguna palabra específica. No creo que haya una explicación formal de por que esto ocurre así, pienso que está relacionado con el uso de las expresiones.
Sin ir muy lejos, en inglés se evidencia mucho este fenómeno en los multi-part verbs que cambian significativamente dependiendo de la palabra que acompañe al verbo central y según cual sea el verbo central.

> break in,break into, break through, break up, break down.
>
> get in, get up, get out, get into, get down

Todos tienen distinto significado y no siempre es muy claro de dónde viene, se utiliza el verbo y la preposición o adverbio de manera muy específica según el significado que quiera darse a la oración.